# How to count the number of ways of choosing of k equal substrings from a List L(the list of All Substrings)

Tags: algorithm

Given a string `S` consisting of `N` lowercase English alphabets.

Suppose we have a list `L` consisting of all non empty substrings of the string `S`.

I need to count the number of ways to choose exactly `K` equal strings from the list `L`(note that length of substring is not necessary to be equal to `k`).
1 ≤ N ≤ 5000
1 ≤ K ≤ 10^9

Exampple:

```
Let S=ababa. 

As List L = {"a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "ab", "ba", "ab", "ba", "aba", "bab", "aba", "abab", "baba", "ababa"}

let k=2
```

The number of ways will be 7:

```
("a", "a")
("a", "a") 
("a", "a") 
("b", "b") 
("ab", "ab") 
("ba", "ba") 
("aba", "aba")
```

Similarly:

```
let k=3
```

The no of ways will be 1:

```
("a", "a", "a")
```

Answer (score 1):

"A list of all substrings". Why would you have a list of all substrings? Let's say you have a string of one million characters, there are 500 billion substrings. The list of all substrings is not at all needed to solve the problem.

If K = 0 then there is one way. 
If K = 1 then there are N ways.

For k = 1 to N, each substring of length k can start at an index from 0 to N - k, that's N - k + 1 substrings. Identify the different strings and count how many there are of each using a hash table. Then for each different string that occurs n times, n >= k, add (n over K) to your count.

That's it.

You can do it faster by looking at strings of length 1 first, ignore all those where you have less than K equal strings, count the number of ways, then add another character to each and repeat. Say K = 5, you had a million characters in the string, and only two substrings of length 6 that occurred five or more times, then you only need to add characters to these two substrings.

Comment: If k=1, the number of ways is the number of substrings, which is O(n^2).  But I think this is the right approach.

Comment: i am not geeting what U have written

Answer (score 0):

Build [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) for given string.

Walk for this array, look for common starting symbols of (at least k) neighbour siffixes.

Comment: Can u provid me the link of suffix array in c

Comment: Try google, I don't know which C implementation is simple and good. An arbitrary one: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/4025 with useful LCP

Answer (score 0):

Here's something in JavaScript:

```js
function choose(n,k){
 if(k>n)return 0;if(k==0||n==k)return 1;var p=n;for(var i=2;i<=k;i++)p*=(n+1-i)/i;return p;
}

function f(str,k){
  var n = str.length,
      h = {},
      count = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
    var s = "";
    for (var j=i; k <= n - j + i && j < n; j++){
      s += str.charAt(j);
      if (h[s])
        h[s]++;
      else
        h[s] = 1;
    }
  }

  for (var i in h)
    count += choose(h[i],k);

  return count;
}
```

Output:

```js
console.log(f("ababa",2));
console.log(f("ababa",3));

7
1
```

Comment: This is really hard to read: 1 letter variable names, a golf scripted choose function, omitting optional {}, and no comments.  Please make it better.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you for your comment. Please help me understand what you mean by "better," because mine sometimes depends on my mood. This time, when I saw your comment, my instinct was to define "better" as giving clues but still leaving something to think about for people to whom it is not entirely obvious already. To address your comment point by point, though, `n`, `i` and `j` are hardly uncommon single letter variables; in fact, they are pretty much ubiquitous; `k` is given, `choose` is common knowledge math, `h` is not hard to guess, and the whole code is akin to many a pseudocode on SO.

Comment: @Teepeemm that said, if there is something specific in my answer you need help with in understanding, please let me know and I'll be glad to assist. As I said, I do not always like to spell everything out in an answer because I think thinking and struggling with something yourself can sometimes be a great learning tool.

Comment: We can agree that a complete answer would be 1 a text explanation, 2 well-written 3 code, and 4 appropriate comments.  I would say 3 is the least important, as OP should be able to reconstruct all four using any of 1, 2, or 4.  But providing only 3 means that OP will have to reverse engineer it (which we agree would be great), or use it as a black box (which we agree would be terrible).  If you want to leave clues for OP, I would suggest 1, 2, or 4, not 3.  (I would classify pseudocode as 2 without 3: it won’t compile, but you can reconstruct everything about it by reading through it.)

Comment: @Teepeemm thanks for explaining your point of view. I think my approach to gauging if an answer is "complete" may be more intuitive, discrete, and harder to explain in words than yours. In this case, the answer seems complete to me, but I'll be glad to try and help you with any specifics you have difficulty with. (I also think you may be applying an unequal standard - read: picking on this answer - since there are so many idiosyncratic, fun, and highly-voted answers on SO which come nowhere near to the standards in your comment.)

Comment: @Teepeemm there is nothing wrong with the OP or anyone else using code "as a black box" - to me that would mean it is useful to them in some way, and perhaps he or she will be ready to understand it sometime in the future. Learning is a process which can take many forms and pacings.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have noticed, you don’t really need the list of substrings.  Because you only care about equal substrings, you only need to count how many times a substring appears, and can use a hash/dictionary/map to keep track of that.  Then, the number of ways to choose exactly `k` equal substrings when a substring appears `n` times is the binomial coefficient `c(n,k)`.  You can add up all of those binomial coefficients for each different substring, and you have your answer.

Notice that if you are asking this question for multiple `k` values, you only need to build the hash/dictionary/map once.

Answer (score -2):

Without any specifics about the languages you're learning in, I believe you can accomplish this with a simple nested loop.  Just compare each value to all values in the array or list.

Comment: This is really vague and not very helpful.  Could you elaborate?