# Efficient All substring counting in sorted order

Tags: java, string, algorithm, suffix-tree, suffix-array

You are given a string find the frequency of all substring sorted(decreasing order) according to there frequency.

Eg: ababa
{"a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "ab", "ba", "ab", "ba", "aba", "bab", "aba", "abab", "baba", "ababa"}.

output:

3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1

explanation

3 a
2 b
2 ba
2 aba
2 ab
1 abab
1 baba
1 ababa
1 bab

solution

1)one obvious solution is to keep all the string in hash map and count it
frequency but it will take o(n^3logn) O(n^2 *n){n^2 number of substring *O(n) for comparision of string *logn(as map is maintened as Red black tree)} 
2)Insert all substring in Ternary search tree then retrive frequency of each substring then sort the frequency O(n^3 logn)

I am wondering is there O(n^2) or O(nlogn) solution exsist.

like this http://www.quora.com/Given-a-string-how-do-I-find-the-number-of-distinct-substrings-of-the-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count the number of ways of choosing of k equal substrings from a List L(the list of All Substrings)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711272/how-to-count-the-number-of-ways-of-choosing-of-k-equal-substrings-from-a-list-l)

Answer (score 1):

An O(n^2) solution can be achieved in this way:

1. Insert all substrings into a trie. This can be done in O(n^2).
2. Obtain all frequency and sort them.
   Note that the frequency of any substring can only be in range [0, n], so a bucket sort can have all of the numbers sorted in O(n^2) since in the worst case there will be n^2 numbers.

Comment: There are O(n^2) substrings,  of O(n) size. Inserting them to a trie is O(n^3).

Comment: But substrings are incremental. so for "abc", inserting "a" "ab" "abc" only takes 3 operations on a trie, not 1+2+3

Comment: Then it's not "insert O(n^2) substrings to a trie", it's something else if you want to use the fact that they are incremental. I am not claiming it cannot be done, I am claiming it's not black box insert O(n^2) substrings.